# Update issues in AngularFire 5.0

Tags: angularfire2

I am working on a `Angular 2 app` which stores the purchase details of user's in firebase. I'm using `AngularFire2` for interacting with firebase. 
The project was working fine until I updated the `angularfire2` library. It is mentioned on their [github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1183) repo that they have made some breaking changes in [AngularFire 5.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).
I tried to update my function calls as mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md).

Still I'm getting the following error.

> ERROR in /Users/manu/Desktop/Bitbucket-2017-repo/angular4-portal/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts (16,92): Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "angular4-portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just solved it by updating as well the angularfire2.
you are still at version 4.0.0.rc0 (I was rc2).
I've updated to latest version 5.0.0-rc.1 and all errors were gone.

run :

> npm uninstall angularfire2

then :

> npm install angularfire2 --save

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was fixed checked the `app.module.ts` IMPORTS.

Can you show me your `app.module.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybee try downgrade to

"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
"firebase": "^3.9.0"

in package.json - this is worked for me in my project.